# Android "forgets" my registered BroadcastReceiver for screen events

Tags: android, android-intent, android-context

Okay, so I have a BroadcastReceiver that handles various events, and one of those that I wanted to handle are screen on/off events. For some reason Android doesn't let you register for these in your manifest, so I have to do this dynamically. The method I settled upon was to  broadcast an app-specific intent when my application is opened, and when my receiver gets this it will add itself for receiving screen on/off events.

This works fine, however Android periodically "forgets" this association, but I'm having a hard time figuring out why; all the events I've registered for in my manifest continue to be received just fine, it just seems to be that the dynamically registered ones stop working if the application is cleared from my device's RAM. I think I can confirm the latter actually because if it has been held in RAM the app will open near instantly, but if it's been cleaned at some point it will take a moment or two to fully open, and screen events will be missing from its log, even though I know they should have occurred.

I'm not doing anything unusual that I can see. Here's a stripped down sample of what I'm doing to register the actions I want (please forgive any typos):

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction() == "com.haravikk.foo.ACTION_ON_OPEN") {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(this, filter);
    }
    // Other events
}
```

In my application I have the following:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(new Intent("com.haravikk.foo.ACTION_ON_OPEN"));

    // Other setup actions
}
```

My only workaround so far is to have my broadcast receiver re-register itself every time it receivers **any** event, but that's not desirable at all, and doesn't really solve the problem as many of the events I'm interested in often only occur after the screen is turned on.

Answer (score 0):

> The method I settled upon was to broadcast an app-specific intent when my application is opened, and when my receiver gets this it will add itself for receiving screen on/off events.

That's not going to work.

> however Android periodically "forgets" this association, but I'm having a hard time figuring out why

Android is terminating your process.

> it just seems to be that the dynamically registered ones stop working if the application is cleared from my device's RAM

Correct.

> My only workaround so far is to have my broadcast receiver re-register itself every time it receivers any event

That does not solve your underlying problem.

The best solution is to redesign your app to not care about screen off/on events. Those are for the foreground application, not background ones.

Your alternative is to try to have an everlasting service, to keep your process around. Then you will need to justify to your users why your app needs to be tying up memory all of the time. Plus, you will need to take care of the cases when your process *still* gets terminated (low memory, OS or third-party task killer, "Force Stop" in Settings).

Comment: Unfortunately my application needs to know when the screen is switched on and off so it can track when the device is likely to be off for a long period. For example, if the user historically switches their screen off around 11pm, and it's then off for 6+ hours, then chances are it's because they've stopped to sleep, so they're not likely to need any of the features of my app. The only compromise I can think of is to instead register for user present, and only check for screen off when that occurs, but it's a bit of a nasty workaround.